# Golang, внести коррекцию в значение времени интервала вывода

Tags: golang

Приведенный ниже код с заданным интервалом в 1 секунду выводит текущее время: секунды и наносекунды.
Хочу получить возможность коррекции интервала в динамике и без потери шага таким образом, чтобы
приблизить этот шаг к тику времени, т.е. максимально уменьшить значение наносекунд.

```
Например, до принятия решения о коррекции имею такой расклад:
1 .  37 _[сек] :  664424700 _[нано]
2 .  38 _[сек] :  665587900 _[нано]
3 .  39 _[сек] :  671653600 _[нано]
4 .  40 _[сек] :  678158100 _[нано]
5 .  41 _[сек] :  672743300 _[нано]
6 .  42 _[сек] :  664778500 _[нано]
7 .  43 _[сек] :  682600800 _[нано]
8 .  44 _[сек] :  668490000 _[нано]
9 .  45 _[сек] :  672649400 _[нано]
10.  46 _[сек] :  678300600 _[нано]
Предполагаю, что, если остановить такой вывод на один шаг и сделать его с дельтой времени так, чтобы
47-ю секунду поймать чуть раньше, то потом опять продолжив вывод с заданным интервалом в 1 сек, 
получу синхронизацию уже без значительного отставания,
например,
11.  47 _[сек] :  ~100000 _[нано]
12.  48 _[сек] :  ~100000 _[нано]
13.  49 _[сек] :  ~100000 _[нано]
14.  50 _[сек] :  ~100000 _[нано]
```

Возможность такой коррекции нужна по команде, т.е. не автоматически.
Имитирую такую команду в коде, - после 10-ой секунды.
Сделать подобие сказанного не получилось.
Остановить вывод в консоли -> Ctr+C

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

var stopper chan<- bool
var cnt = 1
var ns = []int{}
var stat = []string{}

func main() {

    stopper = start_SetInterval()
    fmt.Println("stopper = ", stopper) // 0xc00019cc60 <-- тип данных: chan<- bool

    time.AfterFunc(10*time.Second, func() {
        stop_SetInterval(stopper)
        // fmt.Println("ns = ", ns)
        max := ns[0]
        for _, element := range ns {
            if element > max {
                max = element
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("\n макс. число в массиве = ", max)

        dt := time.Duration(1000000000 - max)
        fmt.Println(" dt = ", dt, "\n ")

        time.AfterFunc(dt*time.Nanosecond, func() {
            handler() // сработает один раз условно сразу - с учётом коррекции: dt;
            stopper = start_SetInterval()
            // fmt.Println(stat)
            // fmt.Println("max = ", max)
            // fmt.Println("коррекция (1сек. - max) = ", dt)
        })
    })

    // pause the console
    <-make(chan bool)
}




func start_SetInterval() (stopper chan<- bool) {
    stopper = SetInterval(handler, 1*time.Second) //
    return
}

func stop_SetInterval(stopper chan<- bool) {
    stopper <- true
}


func handler() {
    t := time.Now()
    s := t.Second()
    n := t.Nanosecond()
    fmt.Println(cnt, ". ", s, "_[сек] : ", n, "_[нано]")
    // stat = append(stat, strconv.Itoa(cnt), ". ", strconv.Itoa(s), "_[сек] : ", strconv.Itoa(n), "_[нано]\n")
    cnt += 1
    ns = append(ns, n)
}



func SetInterval(p interface{}, interval time.Duration) chan<- bool {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(interval)
    stopIt := make(chan bool)
    go func() {

        for {

            select {
            case <-stopIt:
                fmt.Println("stop setInterval")
                return
            case <-ticker.C:
                reflect.ValueOf(p).Call([]reflect.Value{})
            }
        }

    }()

    // return the bool channel to use it as a stopper
    return stopIt
}
```

Comment: наносекунды уходят на вызов вашей функции. поэтому они отличаются. если внимательно посмотреть, но наносекунды увеличиваются. со временем, расхождение будет все больше и больше. поэтому пытливы умы пытаются решить это до сих пор. если вам реально нужна синхронизация до наносекунд, то используйте PTP. PTP достигает точности синхронизации менее микросекунды

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сдаётся мне, то что вы хотите, технически недостижимо.

Во-первых, таймеры в рантайме Go ждут не сами по себе, а используют средства планировщика операционной системы. Поток, который ждёт наступления момента времени в будущем, вызывает системный вызов и блокируется (на самом деле сложнее, планировщих горутин использует epoll/WaitForMultipleObjects, но на последствия это не влияет).

Ядро операционной системы то и дело проверяет, не настало ли время будить. Вся фишка в том, как часто наступает это самое "то и дело". В линуксе Go использует системный таймер с разрешением по умолчанию равным 1.5 миллисекунды, или в терминах нужных вам наносекунд - полтора миллиона наносекунд. В Windows ситуация ещё круче, go использует самый грубый таймер из имеющихся, с разрешением по умолчанию в 16 миллисекунд. Это не приговор, таймер можно улучшить, но точность отсечек времени всё равно не может быть лучше чем 0.5 миллисекунды. То есть полмиллиона наносекунд.

Другими словами, в современных операционных системах на интеловской платформе в принципе нельзя получить точность пробуждения таймера лучше чем полмиллисекунды.

Вот программа, которая пытается обнулить дробную часть секунды. Функция `minimizeSkew` выставляет интервал ожидания таким, чтобы по выходу из ожидания таймера время было целым числом секунд. В последней строке программа печатает среднее отклонение микросекунд от нуля и среднеквадратичное отклонение этой величины.

```
package main

import (
    "math"
    "time"
)

// Минимизировать отклонение наносекунд от нуля
func minimizeSkew() {
    t := time.Now()
    skew := time.Duration(t.Nanosecond())
    dt := time.Second - skew
    if dt < 0 {
        dt += time.Second
    }

    <-time.After(dt)
}

var skew = []int64{}

func step() {
    minimizeSkew()
    t := time.Now()
    ns := int64(t.Nanosecond())
    if ns > 500_000_000 {
        ns = ns - 1_000_000_000
    }
    skew = append(skew, ns)
    println(t.UTC().String(), ns)
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    println(t.UTC().String())

    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        step()
    }

    println(mean(skew)/float64(time.Microsecond), stdDeviation(skew)/float64(time.Microsecond))
}

//
// -- Чутка статистики --
//

// Среднеквадратичное отклонение
func stdDeviation(a []int64) float64 {
    av := mean(a)
    v := meanSquares(a) - av*av
    return math.Sqrt(v)
}

// Среднее значение
func mean(a []int64) float64 {
    var sum float64
    for _, v := range a {
        sum += float64(v)
    }
    return sum / float64(len(a))
}

// Средний квадрат
func meanSquares(a []int64) float64 {
    var sum float64
    for _, v := range a {
        f := float64(v)
        sum += f * f
    }
    return sum / float64(len(a))
}
```

Вывод программы в Linux:

```
2022-10-28 03:35:59.757090508 +0000 UTC
2022-10-28 03:36:00.000730646 +0000 UTC 730646
2022-10-28 03:36:01.000579197 +0000 UTC 579197
2022-10-28 03:36:02.000672707 +0000 UTC 672707
2022-10-28 03:36:03.000605281 +0000 UTC 605281
2022-10-28 03:36:04.000724208 +0000 UTC 724208
2022-10-28 03:36:05.000596079 +0000 UTC 596079
2022-10-28 03:36:06.000606543 +0000 UTC 606543
2022-10-28 03:36:07.000755867 +0000 UTC 755867
2022-10-28 03:36:08.000937046 +0000 UTC 937046
2022-10-28 03:36:09.000341956 +0000 UTC 341956
2022-10-28 03:36:10.000444457 +0000 UTC 444457
2022-10-28 03:36:11.00035097 +0000 UTC 350970
2022-10-28 03:36:12.000510496 +0000 UTC 510496
2022-10-28 03:36:13.000695985 +0000 UTC 695985
2022-10-28 03:36:14.000847283 +0000 UTC 847283
2022-10-28 03:36:15.001070101 +0000 UTC 1070101
2022-10-28 03:36:16.000324846 +0000 UTC 324846
2022-10-28 03:36:17.001152779 +0000 UTC 1152779
2022-10-28 03:36:18.000307846 +0000 UTC 307846
2022-10-28 03:36:19.000445944 +0000 UTC 445944
+6.350118e+002 +2.339022e+002
```

Последняя строка вывода сообщает, что планировщик опаздывает на 630±230 микросекунд.

Вывод программы в Windows:

```
2022-10-28 03:38:19.1106902 +0000 UTC
2022-10-28 03:38:20.0074279 +0000 UTC 7427900
2022-10-28 03:38:21.0067691 +0000 UTC 6769100
2022-10-28 03:38:22.0020304 +0000 UTC 2030400
2022-10-28 03:38:23.0093104 +0000 UTC 9310400
2022-10-28 03:38:24.0041044 +0000 UTC 4104400
2022-10-28 03:38:25.013434 +0000 UTC 13434000
2022-10-28 03:38:26.0050311 +0000 UTC 5031100
2022-10-28 03:38:27.0144051 +0000 UTC 14405100
2022-10-28 03:38:28.0091042 +0000 UTC 9104200
2022-10-28 03:38:29.0034962 +0000 UTC 3496200
2022-10-28 03:38:30.0119417 +0000 UTC 11941700
2022-10-28 03:38:31.0024919 +0000 UTC 2491900
2022-10-28 03:38:32.0111327 +0000 UTC 11132700
2022-10-28 03:38:33.0115486 +0000 UTC 11548600
2022-10-28 03:38:34.0033981 +0000 UTC 3398100
2022-10-28 03:38:35.0125498 +0000 UTC 12549800
2022-10-28 03:38:36.0072529 +0000 UTC 7252900
2022-10-28 03:38:37.0040006 +0000 UTC 4000600
2022-10-28 03:38:38.0142165 +0000 UTC 14216500
2022-10-28 03:38:39.0082834 +0000 UTC 8283400
+8.096450e+003 +4.003099e+003
```

Видите как фигня в Windows творится? Планировщик опаздывает с пробуждением на 8 ± 4 миллисекунды. Какие уж тут нулевые наносекунды.

В линуксе можно попробовать побороться. Если запаздывание таймера стабильно 630 микросекунд, дайвайте их вычтем из времени ожидания в `minimizeSkew`:

```
    dt := time.Second - skew - 630*time.Microsecond
```

Что получится:

```
+4.822640e+001 +3.063759e+002
```

Стало получше, в среднем запаздывание 5 микросекунд, но при этом среднеквадратичное отклонение 300 микросекунд. То есть никаких шансов обнулить наносекунды. Даже микросекунды не обнуляются.

Это было во-первых.

Во-вторых аппаратура x64 в принципе непригодна для жесткого реального времени (а нулевые наносекунды - это жёстче некуда). Тут целый вагон причин:

- алгоритм энергосбережения может недетерминированно останавливать ядра, чтобы изменять частоту в зависимости от нагрузки
- общая шина данных может приводить к тому, что активно читающий-пишуший в память процесс на одном из ядер заставляет другие ядра ждать данные/код непредсказуемым образом.
- наличие общего кэша тоже не способствует детерминизму.

В реальной жизни операционные системы жесткого реального времени работают в одноядерном режиме с отключенным режимом энергосбережения и выключенным кэшем на каких-нибудь PowerPC, MIPS или специализированных ARM. Но и в них редко встречаются таймеры с разрешением лучше чем 1 микросекунда. Ибо дорогое это удовольствие, часто переключать контексты. Есть, конечно, операционные системочки, в которых процессы выполняются в контексте ядра, в них можно дёргать таймер и почаще, но программировать такие системы - это как гулять по минному полю. Ошибка в процессе - заваливается вся система.

В-третьих, в Go ещё есть такая фича как сборщик мусора. На время выполнения сборки потоки блокируются на недетерминированное число микросекунд, что тоже не добавляет точности ожиданию таймера.

Если хотите реальное время, забудьте о Go, Linux/Windows и x64. Вооружайтесь Cи, специализированной операционной системой и не-интеловской железкой. Да хотя бы Raspberry Pi с RT Linux - тесты у людей показывают латентность менее 50 микросекунд.

Как-то так.

Comment: очень хороший ответ

Comment: @SeniorPomidor спасибо )